# cordova ios resolveLocalFileSystemURL ENCODING_ERR in cordova.file.applicationDirectory

Tags: ios, file, cordova

window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(cordova.file.applicationDirectory + 'www/tutorial/comic.json')

results in the failure callback with ENCODING_ERR on device. Works FINE in ios simulator.

iosPersistentFileLocation = Library

iosExtraFilesystems = bundle, library, library-nosync

full paths:

on the device-
file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/0E3CD0FD-BC69-42D1-BBB2-C59682E7F29A/My%20Comics.app/www/tutorial/comic.json

simulator-
file:///Users/admin/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/80E29D25-5164-4869-81F9-E30571D2BE92/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/650AE88A-FD42-469B-90FE-494DF11CFA02/My%20Comics.app/www/tutorial/comic.json

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You neeed root in your iosExtraFilesystems. Even though the docs say it loaded by default. This fixed it.

iosExtraFilesystems = root, bundle, library, library-nosync

Comment: Thank you very much!

<preference name="iosPersistentFileLocation" value="Library" /> 

<preference name="iosExtraFilesystems" value="library,library-nosync,documents,documents-nosync,cache,bundle,root" />

Comment: Can you be more specific? How do you change `config.xml` accordingly?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this may help anybody who struggles with this too ... we had the exact same effect
window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(cordova.file.applicationDirectory ) always faild with FileError 5 (ENCODING_ERROR)
on real device (iPadAir 4th Gen) -> Always File Error 5
But it worked on The iPadAir Simulator(4.th Gen)  without problems ...

after hours and hours bangign our heads against all walls in the office
We were able to resolve this by: "not using es6" in the callback for success --- the good old way works on Simulator & Device
`CONST filePath = cordova.file.applicationDirectory + "www/" window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(filePath ,` **function(fileEntry)**`{ ... });`

instead of `fileEntry => { ...`

Comment: What??? ES6 doesn't work on iOS device?