# ENCODING_ERR when reading image file from absolute URL

Tags: ios, cordova, cordova-plugins, ionic3

I am following [**this guide**](https://golb.hplar.ch/p/Uploading-pictures-from-Ionic-2-to-Spring-Boot) on how to upload an image file using Ionic 3 on an **iPhone Simulator**. However I am stuck at this error printed from console

> {"code":5,"message":"ENCODING_ERR"}

The code is as follows:

```
      this.file.resolveLocalFilesystemUrl(dto.image)
        .then((entry: FileEntry) => entry.file(file => {
          const reader = new FileReader();
          reader.onloadend = () => {
            //do something
          };
          reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
        }))
        .catch(err => console.log(JSON.stringify(err)));
```

the value of dto.image is:

> /Users/myUsername/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/05972D1E-F805-46E4-B164-BB95F116697A/data/Containers/Data/Application/1096409B-6FA3-4660-97AE-EAF3E2472046/tmp/cdv_photo_013.jpg

I am using [ionic native File plugin](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/file/)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9):

seems stupid but this is the solution:

append **file://** at the start of the url string so it would work.

so the start will be like file:///Users....

This is not documented but i have guessed from this link

[cordova ios resolveLocalFileSystemURL ENCODING_ERR in cordova.file.applicationDirectory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29711448/cordova-ios-resolvelocalfilesystemurl-encoding-err-in-cordova-file-applicationdi)

Comment: My app is using **WKWebView** and I tried to use **normalizeURL** but it doesn't work. So I got back to use **file:///**, it works, thanks!

Comment: you saved my life !